# Connect Four in Java for two human players

Tags: java, console, connect-four

Connect Four kinda caught my eye, and I decided to start from the very basics. Here I have bare-bones implementation for playing the game between two human players on the command line:

**Board.java**

```
package net.coderodde.game.connect4;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements the actual Connect Four board.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 28, 2016)
 */
public class Board {

    /**
     * The number of columns in the board.
     */
    private static final int BOARD_WIDTH  = 7;

    /**
     * The number of rows in the board.
     */
    private static final int BOARD_HEIGHT = 6;

    /**
     * The minimum length of a winning pattern.
     */
    private static final int WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH = 4;

    private final PlayerColor[][] board = new PlayerColor[BOARD_HEIGHT]
                                                         [BOARD_WIDTH];

    public int getWidth() {
        return board[0].length;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return board.length;
    }

    /**
     * Performs a ply of the player with the color {@code color} putting a new
     * piece at column {@code x}.
     * 
     * @param x     the column index.
     * @param color the player color.
     */
    public void put(final int x, final PlayerColor color) {
        checkX(x);
        checkColumnNotFull(x);
        Objects.requireNonNull(color, "The input color is null.");

        int y = board.length - 1;

        while (board[y][x] != null) {
            --y;
        }

        board[y][x] = color;
    }

    public PlayerColor checkVictory() {
        if (checkVictory(PlayerColor.RED)) {
            return PlayerColor.RED;
        }

        if (checkVictory(PlayerColor.YELLOW)) {
            return PlayerColor.YELLOW;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        for (int y = 0; y < board.length; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < board[0].length; ++x) {
                if (board[y][x] == null) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int y = 0; y < board.length; ++y) {
            sb.append("|");

            for (int x = 0; x < board[0].length; ++x) {
                final PlayerColor color = board[y][x];
                sb.append(color != null ? color.toString() : " ");
                sb.append("|");
            }

            sb.append("\n");
        }

        sb.append("---------------\n");
        sb.append(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private boolean checkVictory(final PlayerColor color) {
        // Check the horizontal patterns:
        final int horizontalPatterns = getWidth() - WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH + 1;

        for (int startY = 0; startY < getHeight(); ++startY) {
            next_pattern:
            for (int startX = 0; startX < horizontalPatterns; ++startX) {
                // Check a horizontal pattern:
                for (int offset = 0; 
                        offset < WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH;
                        offset++) {
                    if (board[startY][startX + offset] != color) {
                        continue next_pattern;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check the vertical patterns:
        final int verticalPatterns = getHeight() - WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH + 1;

        for (int startX = 0; startX < getWidth(); ++startX) {
            next_pattern:
            for (int startY = 0; startY < verticalPatterns; ++startY) {
                for (int offset = 0;
                        offset < WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH;
                        offset++) {
                    if (board[startY + offset][startX] != color) {
                        continue next_pattern;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check the diagonal patterns (from top-left to bottom-right):
        for (int startY = 0; startY < verticalPatterns; ++startY) {
            next_pattern:
            for (int startX = 0; startX < horizontalPatterns; ++startX) {
                for (int offset = 0;
                        offset < WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH; 
                        offset++) {
                    if (board[startY + offset][startX + offset] != color) {
                        continue next_pattern;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check the diagonal patterns (from top-right to bottom-left):
        for (int startY = 0; startY < verticalPatterns; ++startY) {
            next_pattern:
            for (int startX = WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH - 1; 
                    startX < getWidth();
                    startX++) {
                for (int offset = 0;
                        offset < WINNING_PATTERN_LENGTH; 
                        offset++) {
                    if (board[startY + offset][startX - offset] != color) {
                        continue next_pattern;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        // No victory yet for color 'color'.
        return false;
    }

    public int getColumnHeight(final int x) {
        int height = 0;

        for (int y = board.length - 1; y >= 0; --y, ++height) {
            if (board[y][x] == null) {
                return height;
            }
        }

        return height;
    }

    private void checkX(final int x) {
        if (x < 0) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is negative: " + x);
        }

        if (x >= board[0].length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
                    "The x-coordinate is too large: " + x + ". Must be at " +
                    "most " + (board[0].length - 1) + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkColumnNotFull(final int x) {
        if (getColumnHeight(x) == board.length) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The column at x-coordinate " + x + " is full.");
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerColor.java**

```
package net.coderodde.game.connect4;

/**
 * This enumeration defines the two player colors.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 28, 2016)
 */
public enum PlayerColor {
    RED    ("X"),
    YELLOW ("O");

    private final String string;

    PlayerColor(final String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return string;
    }

    public PlayerColor invert() {
        switch (this) {
            case RED:
                return PlayerColor.YELLOW;

            case YELLOW:
                return PlayerColor.RED;

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.game.connect4;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class ties all the components into a command line Connect Four game.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jun 28, 2016)
 */
public class Main {

    private static final String NEW_GAME_REQUEST = 
            "Do you wish to play once more? Type \"no\" to exit, or anything " +
            "else to replay.";

    private static final String RED_WINS_MESSAGE = 
            "[GAME OVER] The red player wins!";

    private static final String YELLOW_WINS_MESSAGE = 
            "[GAME OVER] The yellow player wins!";

    private static final String TIE_MESSAGE = "[GAME OVER] It's a tie!";

    private static final String EXIT_MESSAGE = "Bye!";

    private static final String RED_PROMPT = "red> ";

    private static final String YELLOW_PROMPT = "yellow> ";

    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Board board = new Board();
    private PlayerColor currentPlayer;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            PlayerColor winnerColor = gameLoop();
            reportOutcome(winnerColor);

            if (!newGameRequested()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(EXIT_MESSAGE);
    }

    private PlayerColor gameLoop() {
        currentPlayer = PlayerColor.RED;
        board = new Board();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(board);

        while (true) {
            PlayerColor winnerColor = board.checkVictory();

            if (winnerColor != null || board.isFull()) {
                return winnerColor;
            }

            final int column = readPly();
            board.put(column, currentPlayer);
            currentPlayer = currentPlayer.invert();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(board);
        }
    }

    private void reportOutcome(final PlayerColor winnerColor) {
        switch (winnerColor) {
            case RED:
                System.out.println(RED_WINS_MESSAGE);
                break;

            case YELLOW:
                System.out.println(YELLOW_WINS_MESSAGE);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println(TIE_MESSAGE);
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean newGameRequested() {
        System.out.println(NEW_GAME_REQUEST);
        final String input = scanner.next().trim().toLowerCase();
        return !input.equals("no");
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }

    private int readPly() {
        while (true) {
            if (currentPlayer == PlayerColor.RED) {
                System.out.print(RED_PROMPT);
            } else if (currentPlayer == PlayerColor.YELLOW) {
                System.out.print(YELLOW_PROMPT);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should not get here.");
            }

            final String command = scanner.next().trim();

            try {
                final int column = Integer.parseInt(command);

                if (column < 1) {
                    System.out.println("Column index must be at least 1.");
                    continue;
                } else if (column > board.getWidth()) {
                    System.out.println("Column index must be at most " +
                                       board.getWidth());
                    continue;
                }

                final int columnIndex = column - 1;

                if (board.getColumnHeight(columnIndex) == board.getHeight()) {
                    System.out.println("The " + nth(column) + " column is " +
                                       "full.");
                }

                return columnIndex;
            } catch (final NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("\"" + command + "\" is not an integer!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static String nth(final int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 1:
                return "1st";

            case 2:
                return "2nd";

            case 3:
                return "3rd";

            default:
                return "" + i + "th";
        }
    }
}
```

Any critique is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Performs a ply of the player with the color {@code color} putting a new
 * piece at column {@code x}.
 * 
 * @param x     the column index.
 * @param color the player color.
 */
public void put(final int x, final PlayerColor color) {
```

First, typo, should be "Performs a play".

Second, why does it take `final int x` when all your documentation contains is "the column index"? Why not... `final int columnIndex`?

```
int y = board.length - 1;
```

This is hard to read. Make use of your own helper methods:

```
int y = getHeight() - 1;
```

---

```
public boolean isFull() {
    for (int y = 0; y < board.length; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < board[0].length; ++x) {
            if (board[y][x] == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Weirdly enough, all that matters for connect-four is that the top row has to be filled in order to block all remaining plays. Perhaps that's not what this method checks, but if you're going to use `isFull` to check if a new move is possible, then what this really should consist of is checking if the top row has any free spaces. There's no need to start from the bottom up.

Comment: You are right. **`makeMove`** would be most sensible name for the **`put`**.

Comment: @coderodde exactly!